# Android database application runs fine on emulator but gives an error on the device

Tags: java, android

I've created a simple database Android app. When I debug or run my application on the Emulator it works fine (i.e it reads and writes the database) but when I run it on the device it is unable to read and write the db. I think I've to update my `DatabaseHelper` class. can anyone help me out...
`DatabaseHelper.java`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.sush.myapp.data.model.UsersCredentials;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Logcat tag
    //private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DemoDB.db";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users";
    private static final String TABLE_SCORES = "Scores";
    private static final String TABLE_SYNCSTATUS = "SyncStatus";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    // USERS Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_USERID = "userID";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "userName";
    private static final String KEY_USERPSWD = "userPswd";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "firstName";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lastName";
    private static final String KEY_USERTYPE = "userType";

    // SCORES Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userID";
    private static final String KEY_GAME_ID = "gameID";
    private static final String KEY_SCORES = "scores";

    // SYNCSTATUS Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_STATRDATE = "startDate";
    private static final String KEY_ENDDATE = "endDate";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";

    // Table Create Statements
    // USERS table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USERID
            + " TEXT," + KEY_USERNAME + " INTEGER," + KEY_USERPSWD + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_USERTYPE + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    // Tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SCORES = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_SCORES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USER_ID 
            + " INTEGER," + KEY_GAME_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_SCORES + " INTEGER," 
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    // todo_tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SYNCSTATUS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_SYNCSTATUS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_STATRDATE + " DATETIME," + KEY_ENDDATE + " DATETIME," + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SYNCSTATUS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SYNCSTATUS);
        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Validate user for login, Return true if correct username and password else return false.
    public Cursor validateUserLogin(String uname, String pswd)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{uname, pswd};
        String query = "SELECT "+KEY_USERID+", "+KEY_USERTYPE+" FROM "+TABLE_USERS+" WHERE "+KEY_USERNAME+" = ? AND "+KEY_USERPSWD+" = ?";
        Cursor cur= db.rawQuery(query, whereArgs);
        //Boolean b = cur.moveToFirst();
        if (cur.moveToFirst() == true)
            //return cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERID));
            return cur;
        else
            return null;
    }

    //To get user full name by passing userID.
    public String getUserFullName(int uID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{Integer.toString(uID)};
        String query = "SELECT "+KEY_FIRSTNAME+" || ' ' || "+KEY_LASTNAME+" AS FullName FROM "+TABLE_USERS+" WHERE "+KEY_USERID+" = ?";
        Cursor cur= db.rawQuery(query, whereArgs);
        int index;
        if (cur.moveToFirst() == true)
        {
            index= cur.getColumnIndex("FullName");
            return cur.getString(index);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }

    //********************** CRUD for Users Table **********************//
    public void insertValues(UsersCredentials uc){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_USERID, uc.getUserID());
        cv.put(KEY_USERNAME, uc.getUserName());
        cv.put(KEY_USERPSWD, uc.getUserPassword());
        cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, uc.getUserFirstName());
        cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, uc.getUserLastName());
        cv.put(KEY_USERTYPE, uc.getUserType());
        cv.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, cv);
    }

    public void deleteRecords() {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from Users");
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

I'm calling following statement in my `HomeLoginActivity.java` to create the database.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HomeLoginActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    Button btnSinup;
    EditText user_ID;
    EditText user_pswd;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DatabaseHelper dbh;
    Cursor cur;
    String name;
    Intent intent;
    int uID, uType;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_login);
        //statement to Create/Open DB
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        dbh = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        user_ID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userID);
        user_pswd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userPswd);
        btnSinup =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnSinup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user_ID.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Enter the user ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (user_pswd.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Enter the password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try{
                        cur = dbh.validateUserLogin(user_ID.getText().toString(), user_pswd.getText().toString());
                        if(cur != null)
                        {
                            startManagingCursor(cur);
                            if(cur.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                uID = cur.getInt(0);
                                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "uID = "+uID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                uType = cur.getInt(1);
                                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "uType = "+uType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cur.close();
                                name = dbh.getUserFullName(uID);
                                if(uType == 3) //Goto Admin Home
                                {
                                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Name = "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent adminHome = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeAdminActivity.class);
                                    adminHome.putExtra("ID", uID);
                                    adminHome.putExtra("userFullName", name);
                                    replaceContentView("home_admin", adminHome);
                                }
                                else //Goto Users Home
                                {
                                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Name = "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent userHome = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeUserActivity.class);
                                    userHome.putExtra("ID", uID);
                                    userHome.putExtra("userFullName", name);
                                    replaceContentView("home_user", userHome);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                cur.close();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            cur.close();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        //cur.close();
                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error = "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String homeID, Intent homeIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(homeID,homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

When I run my app on the Emulator and try to login using userDetails present in the database, its works fine and gets logged in, but when I copy the `.apk` file to the device and after installation when I run the app and try to login it shows Invalid UserInformation.

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas it works fine on the Emulator, only problem come when I run it on the device. I'm not getting any error in my `logcat`. I think this problem is because the `DB` is not present on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for my question. The code above is correct and works fine..
The problem: There was no data in my database tables when I installed on the device.
When we deploy any Android application with database and data in it, that time only database is created on the device there will be no data initially, So we need to do some `Insert` Operation or `Synchronization` from the Server to get the data into the device `DB`.

In my app I'm `Sync` data from the server, so After the Sync it was working fine on device as well.
Hope this will be helpful for `Newbies`.

Answer (score 1):

switch to DDMS perspective and check if db is present at this location
/data/data/YOUR_APP/databases/YOUR_DATABASAE.db

Comment: ya It is created, It is there in `/data/data/myPackageName/databases/DemoDB.db` and `DemoDB.db-journal`

Comment: ok...then copy that file from there and paste is on pc & using sql lite browser check if the required data is present or not!

Comment: How can I copy the DB file i.e `DemoDB.db` from `/data/data/myPackageName/databases/DemoDB.db`, There is no option to copy it..

Comment: in DDMS there is option "pull file from device" using that u can copy file on pc

Comment: Thank you.. I've pulled it to my PC and I checked the data in the database tables. There are all data in the tables..

Comment: ok,now post the code which u are using to retrieve data from the database and comparing it to the user entered data. i think you are making some mistake during retrieving data from database.

Comment: ok I'll post my code. but I've already mentioned that Its fetching the data and working fine in the `Emulator` Only problem is if I take the `.apk` file from the `bin` folder and install on the device that time its now working.... I'll edit the above code and I'll add the database retrieval code

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code to this:

```
  public void insertValues(int uid,String uname,int pass,String first,String     last,String type,int date){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_USERID, uid);
    cv.put(KEY_USERNAME,uname);
    cv.put(KEY_USERPSWD,pass);
    cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, first);
    cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, last);
    cv.put(KEY_USERTYPE,type);
    cv.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, date);
    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, cv);
}
```

In HomeloginActivity i manually inserted record:

```
dbh.insertValues(101,"mohit",123,"mohit", "mohit","1", 12);
```

and entered  username:mohit password:123

it worked fine for me and was able to login.

looks like some problem with your UsersCredential in above code

Comment: even I'm able to login, but only on the Emulator but when I install my app on the device, it shows `invalid username or password`, It means there is no `DB` on the device. I'm able to insert the values to the table without any problem...